# Eclipse 2020-03: java.lang.StackOverflowError on validating Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications

When eclipse start validating my Maven project I receive a java.lang.StackOverflowError. I use the maven version 3.3 external.

This is my pom from my project:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- GWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <!-- "provided" so that we don't deploy -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <!-- "provided" so that we don't deploy -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gwt-dev-calendar</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.advanced-gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>advanced-gwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.knightsoft-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7-0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.20</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the eclipse log where the stack overflow occures:

> 

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-03-18 09:25:11.725
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Validating project_MAVEN".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.json.provisonnal.com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.read(JsonParser.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.json.provisonnal.com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.readStringInternal(JsonParser.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.json.provisonnal.com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.readString(JsonParser.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.json.provisonnal.com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.readValue(JsonParser.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.json.provisonnal.com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.readObject(JsonParser.java:144)
```

I tried already with another eclipse version without success. Could it be a dependency issue in my pom?

Comment: More likely you have a .json file in the project that's causing a problem. Do you have a longer stack trace than that that you could include?

Comment: Correct. I didn't know Eclipse or Maven was going to validate .json that is not taken up in the sources of the project. :-s

Comment: Without the bottom of the stack, it's a little hard to tell what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
>   at org.eclipse.json.provisonnal.com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.readObject(JsonParser.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.json.provisonnal.com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.readValue(JsonParser.java:87)
!SESSION 2021-03-18 10:14:24.966 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=1.8.0_282
java.vendor=Red Hat, Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-03-18 10:28:19.469
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-03-18 10:28:19.469
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@4bd39edc,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@3ba50851,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:25.383
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is set to but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:25.384
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort is set to but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:25.385
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is set to but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:25.385
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is set to but should not be set.

!ENTRY com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.wtp 1 1 2021-03-18 10:28:27.117
!MESSAGE GWT: GWT Facet startup

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-03-18 10:28:32.550
!MESSAGE The POM for cob.plugins.maven:schema-packager-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-03-18 10:28:32.553
!MESSAGE The POM for cob.plugins.maven:schema-packager-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-03-18 10:28:32.554
!MESSAGE The POM for cob.plugins.maven:schema-packager-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

!ENTRY com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:35.441
!MESSAGE Sending POST request to Analytics: {cd1=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product, cd4=com.gwtplugins.eclipse.suite.v3.feature_0.0.0.0, cd3=3.13.700.v20200209-1624, t=event, cd6=GWT 2.8.1, v=1, ea=GWT_COMPILATION, an=GWT Eclipse Plugin, tid=UA-62291716-1, ec=com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update, cd10=1599469239045, cid=1599469239045}

!ENTRY com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:35.441
!MESSAGE Sending POST request to Analytics: {cd1=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product, cd4=com.gwtplugins.eclipse.suite.v3.feature_0.0.0.0, cd3=3.13.700.v20200209-1624, t=event, cd6=GWT 2.8.1, v=1, ea=GWT_COMPILATION, an=GWT Eclipse Plugin, tid=UA-62291716-1, ec=com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update, cd10=1599469239045, cid=1599469239045}

!ENTRY com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:35.444
!MESSAGE Analytics ping request parameters: cd1=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&cd4=com.gwtplugins.eclipse.suite.v3.feature_0.0.0.0&cd3=3.13.700.v20200209-1624&t=event&cd6=GWT%202.8.1&v=1&ea=GWT_COMPILATION&an=GWT%20Eclipse%20Plugin&tid=UA-62291716-1&ec=com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update&cd10=1599469239045&cid=1599469239045

!ENTRY com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:35.444
!MESSAGE Analytics ping request parameters: cd1=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&cd4=com.gwtplugins.eclipse.suite.v3.feature_0.0.0.0&cd3=3.13.700.v20200209-1624&t=event&cd6=GWT%202.8.1&v=1&ea=GWT_COMPILATION&an=GWT%20Eclipse%20Plugin&tid=UA-62291716-1&ec=com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update&cd10=1599469239045&cid=1599469239045

!ENTRY com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:35.490
!MESSAGE Analytics ping response: 200: OK
GIF89a  �� ���   ,       D ;

!ENTRY com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.suite.update 1 0 2021-03-18 10:28:35.491
!MESSAGE Analytics ping response: 200: OK
GIF89a  �� ���   ,       D ;
```